# with conn: AttributeError: __exit__ when using socket to receive message

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I have a script, in python, that need to communicate with another script, in java, through socket, the python script will only receive messages and i'm using a library called mininet to do my stuff and apparently it cant run on python3 so i need to use python2. I currently use python2.7.15+

I searched on stack and i didn't find this problem in the context that i have, apparently the with statement don't implement a context manager and for some reason i need this on the socket fucntion (i'm very unfamiliar with python so if this situation is easily explained by a basic python knowledge forgive me)

```
def start_socket(self):

        HOST = 'localhost'
        PORT = 8888

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print 'Socket created'

        #Bind socket to local host and port
        try:
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        except socket.error as msg:
            print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
            sys.exit()
            print 'Socket bind complete'

        #Start listening on socket
        s.listen(10)
        print 'Socket now listening'

        while 1:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            with conn:
                print('Connected by', addr)
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                message = data.decode(encoding='UTF-8')

                if (message == 'start7'):
                    topo_size = "7"
                    s.close()
                elif (message == 'start6'):
                    topo_size = "6"
                    s.close()
                elif (message == 'start5'):
                    topo_size = "5"
                    s.close()
                elif (message == 'start4'):
                    topo_size = "4"
                    s.close()
                elif (message == 'start3'):
                    topo_size = "3"
                    s.close()
                elif (message == 'start2'):
                    topo_size = "2"
                    s.close()
                elif (message == 'start1'):
                    topo_size = "1"
                    s.close()
            break
```

This function is called on a main function that need to wait a order from the other script in java, and after determines what message is between this seven possible messages, he breaks and proceed with the code. The expected here is that it check what messages is and proceed with the code but what happening is: when the function is called the code blocks until receive a connection and when the other script connects, the python script throws an error saying that there's a problem with the line:

```
with conn:
```

The complete error is:

```
Socket created
Socket now listening
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_initial.py", line 669, in <module>
    teste.run_topo()
  File "script_initial.py", line 643, in run_topo
    self.start_socket()
  File "script_initial.py", line 584, in start_socket
    with conn:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: Similar would happen using: `with "I have no __enter__ or __exit__": pass` - *the error says the object supplied does **not** support the with-statement*. Instead, code has to use a more manual approach such as `socket.close` explicitly (although note that GC triggers a close automatically too).

Comment: Also, the placement of the `break` seems suspicious..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.7 the `socket` object does not support the context manager interface. You therefore cannot use the `with` statement with the `socket` object and have to explicitly call its `close` method after you're done using it.

Change:

```
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            ...
```

to:

```
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connected by', addr)
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        ...
        conn.close()
```

Comment: it solved the problem, also the appointment of user2864740 was correct too